# how to define breakpoints in elevation prop in Paper In MUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am using `MUI5` in my Project. Its great. I have designed a login page. In the Page, I have used `Paper` Component

In the `Paper` Component, I want to define `Elevation`. I can define it using this

```
<Paper elevation={7}>
```

It works. But My need was. For mobile screen/Tab screen, I don't want elevation.So I did like this

```
<Paper elevation={{md:7}}>
```

But it's not working.  Please Help me with some solutions

Here's the Code in my Sand Box
https://codesandbox.io/s/loginpage-6ko3qs?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Paper's `elevation` prop simply maps Material UI's `theme.shadows` to `box-shadow` based on the number.

So you can do this instead of using `elevation` altogether:

```
      <Paper
        sx={{
          width: 500,
          height: 300,
          backgroundColor: "white",
          padding: 5,
          pb: 10,
          boxShadow: { xs: "none", md: "0px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)" }
        }}
      >
.....
</Paper>
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/loginpage-forked-zdijmv?file=/src/App.js

These are all the `boxShadow` attributes that MUI uses for their `elevation` prop:

```
0: "none"
1: "0px 2px 1px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 1px 1px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 3px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
2: "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
3: "0px 3px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 3px 4px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
4: "0px 2px 4px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 4px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
5: "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 5px 8px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 14px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
6: "0px 3px 5px -1px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 6px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 1px 18px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
7: "0px 4px 5px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 7px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 2px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
8: "0px 5px 5px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 8px 10px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 14px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
9: "0px 5px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 9px 12px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 3px 16px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
10: "0px 6px 6px -3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 10px 14px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 18px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
11: "0px 6px 7px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 11px 15px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 4px 20px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
12: "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 12px 17px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 22px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
13: "0px 7px 8px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 13px 19px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 24px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
14: "0px 7px 9px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 14px 21px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 5px 26px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
15: "0px 8px 9px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 15px 22px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 28px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
16: "0px 8px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 16px 24px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 30px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
17: "0px 8px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 17px 26px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 6px 32px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
18: "0px 9px 11px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 18px 28px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 34px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
19: "0px 9px 12px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 19px 29px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 7px 36px 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
20: "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 20px 31px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 38px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
21: "0px 10px 13px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 21px 33px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 40px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
22: "0px 10px 14px -6px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 22px 35px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 8px 42px 7px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
23: "0px 11px 14px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 23px 36px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 44px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
24: "0px 11px 15px -7px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0px 24px 38px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.14),0px 9px 46px 8px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)"
```